# Very strange C behavior

Tags: c++, c

Hi something really strange is happening in the following simple program. The program takes ASCII numbers of 2 digits because i only need to read numbers, the '@' symbol and the '.' symbol. And finds out what is the ASCII symbol for this bytes.

```
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
 unsigned int ch;


char aux[256];

 strcpy(aux,argv[1]);

 char a[0];

 char buff[50];
 char result[512];
 int i=0;

 while(i lessThan strlen(argv[1]))
 {   
     a[0]=aux[i];
     a[1]=aux[i+1];
     a[2]='\0';
     ch = atoi(a);
      printf("el int:%d \n",ch);
      sprintf(buff,"%c",ch);

       printf("el char: %s \n", buff);
       i=i+2;
   }

 }
```

Ok this is working and in the variable buff is printing all the ASCII symbols the right way. But as u can see i have a `char[]` called result that is never used. So i delete it. and i get a different result when i run the program again :O. For some reason the program does not read the '.' character any more :( WHY???? please someone explain me i am scared lol!

my results with variable result declare:

```
 ./try3 494650526450

    el int:49

    el char: 1 

    el int:46 

    el char: . 

    el int:50 

    el char: 2 

    el int:52 

    el char: 4 

    el int:64 

    el char: @ 

    el int:50 

    el char: 2
```

my results with out variable result declare:

```
 ./try3 494650526450

    el int:49 

    el char: 1 

    el int:0 

    el char:  

    el int:50 

    el char: 2 

    el int:52 

    el char: 4 

    el int:64 

    el char: @ 

    el int:50 

    el char: 2
```

Comment: Why have you declared a zero-length array?  (`char a[0];`).  What is `lessThan`?

Comment: what is " while(i lessThan strlen(argv[1]))" lessThan an operator ?

Comment: In fact, You are strange, not C...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a [zero-length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html), a GNU extension. Change `char a[0];` to `char a[3];`. Declaring another unused char array changes the layout of the memory, that's why it appears to "work".

Comment: I had to do that because the param argv[1] was being saved in char a[2] but when i did that i didnt had the code a[2]='\0'! Now i a[0] to a[3] with the a[2]='\0' and is Working perfec! :) thx guys

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is the use of an empty array: `char a[0]` declares an array without elements (something which is illegal in C++; I'm not good in C but I think in this context it is also prohibited for C).  This array needs to be at least 3 elements wide.

Other than that, this program is riddled with problems. Those I spotted:

- it is obviously missing the headers `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>`
- the number of arguments passed isn't checked before the first argument is accessed
- the length of the first argument isn't taken into account when `strcpy()` to an array (this should be `strncpy()`)
- as already mentioned `char a[0];` declares an empty array
- `lessThan` isn't part of either C or C++
- `i` is a signed integer while `strlen()` returns an unsigned integer and mixed sign comparison are generally a bad idea (although they won't create a problem in this case)
- determining the length of the length of a string in every iterator is slow
- when printing to a string you generally want to use `snprintf()` (although in this case the array won't be overun)

Answer (score 1):

You have taken a zero length array `char a[0]` and accessing upto three elements. Therefore you need to get atleast 3 locations allocated `char a[3]`.

The probable cause of the output is because the allocation of the `result` on the stack is adjacent to the `a` array when you access `a[1]` or more, it will access outside the boundary of `a` (as it is 0 length), and practically insert into the memory location of other arrays. Writing in such location will corrupt the data of that location.